# Work with Steam Web API

Tags: php, steam-web-api

Кто нибудь работал со Steam API? Подскажите, как мне вывести инвентарь пользователя из определенной игры?

Это ссылка для входа.

```
<a href="https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login?openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0&
openid.mode=checkid_setup&
openid.return_to=http://dotawp.esy.es&
openid.realm=http://dotawp.esy.es&
openid.ns.sreg=http://openid.net/extensions/sreg/1.1&
openid.identity=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select&
openid.claimed_id=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select">Steam</a>
```

После залогинивания меня переправляет на сайт:

```
http://dotawp.esy.es/?openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.mode=id_res&openid.op_endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Fsteamcommunity.com%2Fopenid%2Flogin&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fsteamcommunity.com%2Fopenid%2Fid%2F76561198199155851&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fsteamcommunity.com%2Fopenid%2Fid%2F76561198199155851&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Fdotawp.esy.es&openid.response_nonce=2016-07-20T12%3A44%3A35Z9IU5maWEliqztINzvh0caJU5VvU%3D&openid.assoc_handle=1234567890&openid.signed=signed%2Cop_endpoint%2Cclaimed_id%2Cidentity%2Creturn_to%2Cresponse_nonce%2Cassoc_handle&openid.sig=fMG7BmvqlfIsff8ihl69tJ9GXp4%3D
```

Отсюда я беру openid_claimed_id

```
if(!empty($_GET['openid_claimed_id']))
{
    $urljson = file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=<keyApp>F&steamids=<openid_claimed_id>");
    $data = (array) json_decode($urljson)->response->players[0];
    echo $data['profileurl'];
}
else
{
    printf( "\nend");
}
```

Comment: в доках такое точно есть т.к. делал подобное. Да и в интернете есть API Для стима с набором методов получения чего либо

Comment: Привет. Вижу вопрос по STEAM API. Вопрос, есть ли у Вас возможность скинуть код авторизации на сайт Steam`а ? Или же просто объяснить как мне самому можно разобраться с документацией ? Нашёл по этой ссылке : https://steam.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/steam.webauth.html

Answer (score 1):

Для получения можно воспользоваться как SteamAPI, так и Community URL.

У пользователя есть несколько индентификаторов, такие как

```
Vanity URL - hiimsomeuser
Steam64 ID -  123456789xxxxxxxx
Steam32 ID  - STEAM_0:1:12345678
AccountID - [U:1:12345678]
```

---

**SteamAPI**

Для получения на примере TF2 есть такой код:

```
http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItem_{Application ID}/GetPlayerItems/v0001/?key={Your Key}&SteamID={player 64 bit steam id}&format={json/xml/vdf}
```

[Список Application ID](http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2)

---

**Community URL**

Для получения инвентаря так же можно воспользоваться следующими ссылками:

```
http://steamcommunity.com/id/<CUSTOMURL>/inventory/json/<APPID>/<CONTEXTID>
http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/<PROFILEID>/inventory/<APPID>/<CONTEXTID>
```

Первая ссылка предоставлена для `Vanity URL`, вторая для `Steam32 ID`.

Посмотреть `<APPID>` для конкретной игры [Список Application ID](http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2)

Параметр `<CONTEXTID>` означает выбираемые предметы: 1 - игровые вещи, 3 - купоны, 6 - карточки. Вас скорее всего интересует первый.

Comment: Как получить Vanity URL, Steam32 ID, Steam64 ID, AccountID?

Comment: @SanychGoilo посмотреть в URL на странице профиля пользователя добавив к ней `?xml=1`, тем самым получив `Steam64 ID` и из него вытянуть всю остальную информацию через `GetPlayerSummaries (v0002)`. Ну еще есть вариант с авторизацией OpenID, который описан на главной странице документации.

Comment: Что это за openId? Это сторонний сервис какой-то?

Comment: @SanychGoilo, [да, сторонний сервис](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID) с которым сотрудничает Steam, как использовать [в документации](http://steamcommunity.com/dev) это прямо на главной странице написано.

Comment: А совершать обмен вещами api позволяет, или нужно писать независимого бота, который будет это делать?

Comment: @SanychGoilo, обмен требует нескольких действий от самого пользователя, поэтому пишется бот который большинство проделает за него, от пользователя нужно только согласие. Но в общем-то все уже написано за Вас и лежит на GitHub, надо только поискать.

Comment: Привет. Вижу вопрос по STEAM API. Вопрос, есть ли у Вас возможность скинуть код авторизации на сайт Steam`а ? Или же просто объяснить как мне самому можно разобраться с документацией ? Нашёл по этой ссылке : https://steam.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/steam.webauth.html

Comment: @VitalikShchudlo, проще задавать вопросы, чем так спрашивать и больше шанс, что увидит человек, который разбирается. Это у вас сторонний модуль Python, вроде там приложен даже код. Если я не ошибаюсь, то API не авторизует в аккаунт, вы можете только через OpenID попросить пользователя авторизоваться, где его перебросит на сайт самого стима и вам потом вернется только его SteamID. Для больше придется вести себя как клиент и отправлять прямые запросы под видом стима.